Pgbouncer Sidecar: Addressing connection pooling and load balancing issues
I'm currently using TypeORM with RDS Aurora PostgreSQL, and I'm considering introducing PgBouncer to address the following two issues:

The node-postgres library used by TypeORM doesn't support the min pool option.
Due to RDS endpoint caching, the load isn't evenly distributed across instances.

After discussing with colleagues, we concluded that setting up PgBouncer centrally with an HA configuration might create a single point of failure, so we're leaning towards trying a sidecar approach as it seems less risky.
However, I'm concerned that with the sidecar approach, we might not be able to fully leverage the connection pooling benefits of PgBouncer. I'm wondering if there's a way to configure the sidecar setup to still address the two problems mentioned above. Do you have any suggestions on how I could achieve this?
In our tests, we found that a configuration with one PgBouncer as a sidecar per application didn't seem to provide the benefits of connection pooling.
And reducing the DNS caching time to 1 second or setting the server_round_robin option appeared to improve the second issue (load distribution across instances).
I'm curious if there are any other tips or considerations we should keep in mind.
